# CakePHP debug set to 1 throws header error for specific site links

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, warnings

I have an ajax generated search results page which shows all results just fine. There are specific links that I echo out for each record:

1. when any of these links are clicked, the below Warning is generated:

   **core.php: Configure::write('debug', 1);**

   Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/app/views/helpers/link.php:11) [ROOT/httpdocs/cake/libs/controller/components/request_handler.php, line 758]
2. If I set the debug to 2, the Warning does not show:

   **core.php: Configure::write('debug', 2);**

No Warning! ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Yup it was white space in my custom Link helper. I wasted some StackOverflow db!